# Auto Complete textbox using angularjs asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, autocomplete

I am creating a web app in asp.net using angular js I am getting user name from table in JSON format and I want an auto complete text box,
here is my text box

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bordertext" ng-model="myname" ng-change="textchange(myname)" />
```

this is my textbox with `ng-model="myname"` and `ng-change="textchange(myname)"`

in my angularjs i am getting data on pageload,

here is my example data,

```
$scope.data = "{'name':'ibrahim'},{'name':'nizam'},{'name':'shahid'},{'name':'shahrukh'}";
```

and ng-change function

```
 $scope.textchange = function (param) {
            }
```

Now I want to create an auto complete text box with these records

how should it be done?

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete should help

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = [
    {'name': 'ibrahim'},
    {'name': 'nizam'},
    {'name': 'shahid'},
    {'name': 'shahrukh'}
];

for (i = 0; i <= $scope.data.length; i++) {
    if(param == $scope.data[i].name)
       $scope.myname = $scope.data[i].name;
}
```